# Is there a way to handle async steps in specflow?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, specflow

I have a step class that has steps required to call async API and assert against it. Currently it looks like that:

```
[Given(@"a setting from API is correct")]
public async void GetSetting()
{
    var setting = (await GetSettingsFromApi).Setting;
    Assert.IsTrue(setting);
}
```

There are couple problems here:

1. I need this step to be performed at the correct time - after the previous and before the following, unsurprisingly. They can be sync or async, but they don't await each other. Making sure it's executed exactly first would also do. Is there a way to achieve it? Beside hardcoding all steps to explicitly await each other?
2. Assert failure exception is suppressed - it is shown in the in the debugger, but scenario is not stopped and failed as it should? Can I make it pass through and fail the test when the await result is received? This one is actually more important - if test is failed correctly on assert it's doesn't matter if that happens a bit later than expected.

Comment: Use `async Task`, not `async void`. According to [this](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/542), SpecFlow definitely supports async/await, but an `async void` method can't be awaited.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, worked for assert exception, thanks!